# phpMyAdmin unable to start/missing?

Tags: phpmyadmin, fedora

I installed phpMyAdmin in the fedora and when i started the localhost it didn't work. How am I going to fix the error?

**phpMyAdmin - Error**
 ]
   #2002 - No such file or directory
   The server is not responding (or the local server's socket is not correctly configured).

I tried to create mysql link in the /tmp folder and i restarted it.

Answer (score 0):

First, MySQL error 2002 is "Can't connect" but for some reason, your MySQL server does not have the error messages file.

Verify whether your MySQL server is running, which the "mysql" command-line utility.